# Photoshop CS5: duplicate layers with "smart objects"

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'd like to make use of photoshop's "Smart Objects" to have an easier time managing my layers. I have about 20 layers that will be duplicated 10 times... and I'd rather manipulate them as single objects than as 20 layers each.

I created a smart object out of the 20 layers... when I duplicated the smart object, and edited to newly duplicated object... any edits also affected the original.

Is there a way to make distinct smart objects out of duplicates so they can be edited independently?

Comment: How to do this has been answered already. I just wanted to add that maybe groups is a better choice than smart objects in this case as this seems to be defying the purpose of smart objects. just a thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Photoshop forums http://forums.adobe.com/thread/371954

```
If the SO is duplicated by choosing New Smart Object via Copy in the
context menu (control-click on the SO in the layers palette), the new
SO is independent of original: edits in one will not be replicated in
the other.
```